# Connectedness being a topological property?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

So in Pugh's "Real Mathematical Analysis", he asserts that:

> If $M$ is connected and $M$ is homeomorphic to $N$, then $N$ is
>   connected.

If I wanted to show that the intervals $(a, b)$ and $(a, b]$ are not homeomorphic, does it then suffice to show that one (namely $(a, b)$) is connected and the other (namely $(a, b]$) is not connected?

Thanks.

Comment: $(a, b]$ is connected, though. The way I would go about it is to point out that a homeomorphism gives a bijection between open sets in $M$ and in $N$ and similarily between closed sets in either space. If you further point out that in a connected space the only sets both open and close are the whole space and the empty set you are well on your way. **Edit** I thought your goal was to prove the assertation. Sorry.

Comment: They are both connected!

Answer (score 4):

Both $(a,b)$ and $(a,b]$ are connected. However, you can show that they’re not homeomorphic by showing that if you remove any point from $(a,b)$, the resulting space is not connected, while removal of $b$ from $(a,b]$ leaves a connected space.

As a useful exercise concerning a useful fact, you should try to show that the connected subsets of $\Bbb R$ are precisely the intervals $(a,b)$, $(a,b]$, $[a,b)$, and $[a,b]$ (where in this case we may have $a=b$), and the rays $(a,\to)$, $(\leftarrow,a)$, $[a,\to)$, and $(\leftarrow,a]$.

Comment: Thanks. What you said in the first paragraph makes intuitive sense, but why _exactly_ does it show that they are not homeomorphic to each other?

Comment: @RyanYu: If $f:X\to Y$ is a homeomorphism, then for all $x\in X$, $f|_{X\setminus\{x\}}:X\setminus\{x\}\to Y\setminus\{f(x)\}$ is a homeomorphism (it is a continuous bijection with continuous inverse $f^{-1}_{Y\setminus\{f(x)\}}:Y\setminus\{f(x)\}\to X\setminus\{x\}$).  Hence $X\setminus\{x\}$ is connected if and only if $Y\setminus\{f(x)\}$ is.  In this case, if there were a homeomorphism $f:(a,b]\to(a,b)$, it would imply that there is a homeomorphism from $(a,b)$ to $(a,b)\setminus\{f(b)\}$, which is impossible.